# Is there any way to get particular color from gray using CSS filter property?

Tags: css, colors, css-filters

I need to change color of icon on hover from gray(**#b7b7b7**) to coral(**#b45d64**).

I found out that make gray color from coral using CSS filter pretty easy. So for now I use reverse solution, change color of all icons to coral in Photoshop and set CSS filter to gray, as in below code example and on hover disable CSS filter using **none** value.

But I wonder is there any algorithm or way to get particular color like **#b45d64** from gray. I used sepia and play manually with brightness, saturate, and hue-rotate filters, but I there an easier way to do this (I mean easier way to calculate brightness, saturate, and hue-rotate to get #b45d64 from gray using sepia)?

```css
.makegray:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.72) saturate(0) hue-rotate(0deg);
    filter: brightness(1.72) saturate(0) hue-rotate(0deg);
}

.makecoral:hover{
    -webkit-filter: sepia(1) brightness(0.54) saturate(2) hue-rotate(305deg);
    filter: sepia(1) brightness(0.54) saturate(2) hue-rotate(305deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/b7b7b7/fff.png&text=hsla(0,00x25,720x25)" class="makecoral" alt=""><br>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/b45d64/fff.png&text=hsl(355,+370x25,+540x25)" class="makegray" alt="">
```

Comment: Frankly, none I'm aware of. Your current technique seems optimal

Comment: *or tool* You can't request recommendations for tools. Normally I'd just edit that out of an otherwise good question but it's such a small change (normally the question has other things to improve) and I'm under 2K so I figured I'd just point out that part sounds like a rec/find request.

Comment: @BSMP Thank you that pointed to that, I edited my question.
Paulie_D Thank you for you comment.

Comment: AFAIK, `sepia()` is the only filter capable of transforming something grayscale into something non-grayscale, and that's exactly the approach you've taken.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference an SVG filter from your CSS, then you can get a specific color. SVG filter snippet below. For your specific color replace the .7/.4/.5 with the unitized value of your RGB values.

```
<filter id="colorme" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .7  0 0 0 0 .4  0 0 0 0 .5  0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
```